# TypeScript type tracking

Tags: typescript, generics

Infer types like below.

```
interface Char<T> {
    test(values:T);
}

class A<T> {
    test(values: T) {
    }

    // T will extend from other class
    cast<U extends {}>(caster: <X>() => Char<U>) {
        return caster<U>();
    }
}

class B<T, U = T & { b: string }> extends A<U> {
}

function bCaster() {
    return function <T>() {
        return new B<T>();
    };
}

const a = new A<{ a: string }>();

// type inferred the {a}
a.test({a: 'a'});

const b = a.cast(bCaster());

b.test({a: 'a', b: 'b'}); // type error
```

`b.cast`

type inferred T & {a}, when use `U extends T` or `U extends T & {}`

type inferred T & {b}, when use `U extends {}`

but want to be {a, b}

What is the right generic?
is this possible?

Comment: What is `Char`?  Can you be more descriptive about what you're trying to achieve?  I expect this will end up failing to infer due to lack of extensive support for [higher kinded types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213).

Comment: @jcalz  It was just interface, I read your link, It's seems to not work at now. is right?

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know why you want this, nor do I understand how that code is supposed to work.  But if you can change the definition of `A.cast` to:

```
cast<U extends {}>(caster: () => Char<T & U>) {
    return caster();
}
```

this should provide the inference you're looking for, I think.  Without proper support for [higher kinded types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), there isn't much use in having the `caster` callback parameter be generic; instead, treat it as a non-generic function which takes no parameters and returns a `Char<T & U>`.  The return value of `bCaster()` is generic, but assignable to this non-generic type.  Does that work for you?

---

As an aside, I would replace

```
class B<T, U = T & { b: string }> extends A<U> { ... }
```

with

```
class B<T> extends A<T & {b: string}> { ... }
```

unless you have some reason to allow manually overriding `U`.

---

Hope that helps.  Good luck.

Comment: I wanted to add the generic and methods for anytime, with the type infer.
your answer are working right, but cannot recognize `B` methods.
I think so if I still want to type infer, it will not work.